# How to know which generated button was pushed in listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a WP7 app and have a listbox with generated buttons all supposed to lead to somewhere specific. I can't figure out how to know which button was pushed at runtime. The list gets generated from a collection of objects with a couple of attributes in each. One of those attributes contain a value that I need to get to be able to know where to send the user.

So my desired process is that the user clicks on an item in the listbox, passing the value of the attribute in the object the button was generated from, to a click handler which sends the user to the right place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your ListBox contains a ItemTemplate which constructs a Button for each of the items bound to your list? if this is the case, within your Click event handler you need to inspect the DataContext of the button that was clicked:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button btn = sender as Button;
  var myObject = btn.DataContext;
}
```

As an aside, if you are using this for navigation, a ListBox will not give you very good performance. See the following blog post for an alternative:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/a-fast-loading-windows-phone-7-navigationlist-control/

Comment: Great, the only thing that was unclear to me was how to handle the Datacontext but this is actually the object that the button was generated from. To anyone else in the same situation; debug and look at "var myObject" after it has been assigned, this will clear up any questionmarks regarding what type it should be cast to.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `sender` property of the `OnClick` event handler for the click handling.

Alternatively you may want to handle the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox and then query the contents of the SelectedItem.

Comment: This approach was a bit more tedious but it worked as well so +1 :)